# Error in R when connecting to Google Analytics API (Error in curl, Timeout was reached)

Tags: r, google-analytics, connection, google-analytics-api

I was trying to directly pull GA data through R but it kept throwing the following error:

```
Authentication complete.
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached: [accounts.google.com] Connection timed out after 10006 milliseconds
```

The script I used to pull the GA data was as below:

```
library(tidyverse); library(zoo); library(scales); library(lubridate)
library(RGoogleAnalytics)
require(RGoogleAnalytics)
library(gridExtra); library(grid)
library(httr)
library(curl)

client.id <- "****"
client.secret <- '****'

token <- Auth(client.id,client.secret)
```

Does anyone have any ideas why there is always a timeout error? Thank you!